# Text Input Limited to Options

Tags: php, jquery, html, input

I would like people to be able to type into a text input such that as they type any matching results from a list of names is shown in a dropdown. I would like it such that a user cannot select an input that they type, it has to be from a given list of names. That is, the input itself doesn't POST, but it brings up options for a user to click which takes them to a static page. I am aware of `<datalist>` but I don't like that it isn't supported by Safari and some mobile browsers, and am not sure it disallows custom inputs. I'm also aware of jQuery's Autocomplete but am also not sure if it disallows custom inputs.

An example of what I would like can be found in the main search box on http://futhead.com. When you type in a search such as "Roon" it will bring up any names with "Roon" somewhere within. It won't allow you to just click enter and search for "Roon", you must choose one of the options from the dropdown.

I don't have a problem extracting the list from the database, I can do that. It's just the text input bit that I am struggling with.

Comment: No really, it's us who thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use some autocomplete component (like this mentioned from jQuery) and then just check the value given by the user on the submit event (and allow if value has been found or discard in other case)?

Comment: @AdamM That could be a possibility. Would there be an elegant way to do that such that a refresh wouldn't be required? Could it be implemented such that a dialog box says "Must choose from list" or so?

The other issue is that jQuery's Autocomplete has a funny matching method. I believe it matches anything that contains the letters you type anywhere (e.g. typing "gl" would match with "Algol" because there is a g in "Algol" and an l in "Algol" in any position. Do you know if this can be changed?

Comment: Well you can customize it as you want if you know how :) I see you have not much experience with the jQuery do you? If you can wait with this one till the weekend I could help you solve that (on the weekend I have more time to write the code :D)

Comment: I think this is possible with the [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) library, although the precise variant of its functionality that I think you'll want was only recently added and is not documented. See near the end of https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1345 for some guidance. Sorry I'm not intimately familiar enough with the library to give a more detailed answer.